# Omnifaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler + <error-page> generates ContextNotActiveException

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I'm having problems accessing any view(xhtml) of my application. javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: If I set error-page tag, the following exception occurs when accessing any view. The application works normally, but when accessing any view that exception occurs. If I remove the configuration of error-page tag, the exception does not occur. I'm using primefaces 4 + WAS 8.5.5.1 (MyFaces + OpenWebBeans). 
I'll appreciate any help

```
<!-- JSF Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Ominifaces -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping> 

<!-- error -->
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/paginas/erro/sessaoExpirada.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
    <location>/paginas/erro/erro500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

**Edit:** 
I noticed that the error only occurs when I set the tag error code.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/paginas/erro/erro500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

If I set only exception-type tag, the problem does not occur.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
    <location>/paginas/erro/erro500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Below is the stack trace

```
00000082 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause facesServlet: javax.servlet.ServletException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:221)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3328)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleException(WebApp.java:3856)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3837)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)

Caused by: javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread
at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:321)
at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.getContextualInstance(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:124)
at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.invoke(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:95)
at org.apache.webbeans.conversation.ConversationImpl_$$_javassist_4.isTransient(ConversationImpl_$$_javassist_4.java)
at org.apache.webbeans.jsf.WebBeansPhaseListener.beforePhase(WebBeansPhaseListener.java:93)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.PhaseListenerManager.informPhaseListenersBefore(PhaseListenerManager.java:76)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:160)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:119)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
```

*** Edit 2 *** If I remove the 404 error-page definition, the exception is not thrown

```
<!-- error -->
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/paginas/erro/sessaoExpirada.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
    <location>/paginas/erro/erro500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/paginas/erro/erro500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>       
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/paginas/erro/erro403.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

    <!-- this definition throws the exception -->   
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/paginas/erro/erro404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: original message edited. Thanks for reply

Comment: Looks like the error is in error page itself. Are you referencing any beans in there? To exclude one and other, try with "empty" error pages, just printing some test text. As least, get rid of all EL expressions and add them back one by one until the error reoccurs (at that point you nailed down the cause).

Comment: Balusc, I noticed that the error only occurs when I set the error page for HTTP 404 code. Even using a simple text ("error 404"), the error occurs. For error pages 500 and 403 the problem does not occur. There is a correct order for this definition of error pages? I edited the original post and put all my setting for error pages. Thanks for your help
PS: sorry for my "poor english"

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem and this is now a known bug in WAS v8.5.5.x

We opened a PMR by IBM, and just received a fix from them:  this is APAR PI26908

I don't know if it will be included in WAS v8.5.5.4 or not (We use WAS v8.5.5.3 now)

Also with this fix, we need to set com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.deferServletRequestListenerDestroyOnError=true on the web container

You should contact then to receive this iFix

Answer (score 3):

Maybe too late, but some more information:

- the APAR: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI26908
- the "fix": http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/hu/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rweb_custom_props.html#com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.deferServletRequestListenerDestroyOnError

Short: should add a custom property to `server.xml` containing the following:

```
<webContainer deferServletRequestListenerDestroyOnError="true" />
```

The description of the property: "If this custom property is set to true, the web container enables CDI to work properly on custom error pages" (property defaults to false)